# Ruby on Rails - Automatically insert data into DB without seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, seeding

I've some `.json` files with data that are automatically updated from time to  time. I also have a Ruby on Rails app where I want to insert the information that's in those files.

By now, I'm parsing the JSON and inserting the data in the database in the `seeds.rb` file, but I'll want to add more data without having to restart the app, I mean, on the go.

From time to time, I'll check those files and if they have modifications, I want to insert those new items into my database.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Does the JSON data map to your existing models? Can you expose your controllers as a REST API and use that to insert your JSON data?

Comment: The data doesn´t map to the existing models, but each `json` file has a specific name that corresponds to a model, and only has entries of that model. My controllers are almost `scaffold` like, by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for a cron.

Create the code you need in a rake task (in /lib/tasks):

```
task :import, => :environment do
    Importer.read_json_if_modified # your importer class
end
```

Then run this with the period you want using your system's cron.

Comment: What means that `importer class`?

Comment: It's just an example: you'll have to write the code that read your JSON and create the appropriate objects. You can either put it directly inside the Rake task, but I would probably move it into a dedicated, separated class.

Comment: It was that. Thank you, @Martin.